# Designing a high intensity flash attachment for airsoft rifle

Tags: capacitor, flash, light

Dear readers of this community,

I've been looking into starting an electrical project and in my research I've often came across this community. Because none of the topics fully covered my question, I decided to ask a question of my own.

I play airsoft as a hobby (a team-based shooting game, similar to paintball) and many players (myself included) have a flashlight as attachment on their rifle. The thing is, this flashlight is mostly used to blind other players, instead of lighting your own path, so that got me thinking.

Would it be possible to create a capacitor-driven flash that would deliver more lumens in a fairly small/light package? I've looked into it myself and have considered the following options:

- modifying a camera flash
- a capacitor-driven LED
- a capacitor-driven Xenon headlight (from a car)
- a capacitor-driven flash bulb

The first option doesn't appear to be a good option, since most camera flashed don't deliver a lot of lumen or are either very pricey.

The other options would require a DIY circuit. I've been trying to design a circuit (in a program called Yenka, formerly Crocodile Physics) as I have some basic electrical knowledge (physics teacher), but not enough to confidently make the right choices.

I am therefore hoping some of you will be willing to share your wisdom on the matter. I am mainly curious as to which option seems best to you guys, and for some guidance for the circuit. One problem I've encountered is choosing a resistance for the charging circuit for the capacitor. A higher resistance results in a longer charge time and a lower charging current, but what is an acceptable current for a battery and a capacitor?

EDIT: Another thing I found regarding the LED: apparently they work better on a LED-driver. Is that a necessary component or would it work on a capacitor?

Thank you for your attention and your reply in advance!

Comment: Safety might be a consideration when blinding people.

Comment: Have you researched just hacking a one shot camera? (its cheap and contains a ready built circuit board and just needs a couple of wires for power and trigger). The lumen count is fine if you make it into a narrow beam using lenses. Flash gun optics attempt to spread the light evenly over the area covered by the camera lens.

Comment: Andy aka: You're absolutely right, obviously not looking to cause any damage. Just think a souped up camera flash, enough to leave an afterimage and disorient a bit.

Jim Dearden: Good suggestion, didn't think of that. Can't remember the last time I used one of those, so not sure about the brightness.